# How to add URL to IDM by program

Tags: vb6, download

How to add URL to IDM by program ? I am trying to develop a software what to add URL to the IDM. I have no idea how to do that could help me ? I found this temp folder C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\IDM\DwnlData but no idea how to add URL.

Comment: What is IDM? If you mean the [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/), you'll need to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add links to IDM by passing the "-d" argument to IDMan.exe

From in your program or script, (you can use ShellExecute or the equivalent in whatever language you're using,) call [IDM Install Path]\IDMan.exe -d [link]

[IDM Install Path]: The directory where idm is installed
(eg. C:\Program Files\Internet Download Manager)

[link]: The url you want to add to IDM

[enter link description here](http://www.quizzyssoftware.com/)

Let us know if there is anything else we can help u with